# Kubernetes Automated Rollbacks

Tags: kubernetes

I was trying to find some alternative for docker-swarm `rollback` command, which allows you to specify rollback strategy in the deployment file.
In k8s ideally it should use `readinessProbe`, and if didn't pass `failureThreshold` it should rollback, before starting deployment of the next pod (to avoid downtime).

Currently, in my deployment script, I'm using hook `kubectl rollout status deployment $DEPLOYMENT_NAME || kubectl rollout undo deployment $DEPLOYMENT_NAME`, which works, but it's not ideal because first rollout command will trigger error way after unhealthy pod will be deployed and a healthy one will be destroyed which will cause downtime.

Ideally, it shouldn't even kill current pod before a new one will pass `readinessProbe`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no specific rollback strategy in a Kubernetes deployment. You could try a combination of [RollingUpdate](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#rolling-update-deployment) with [max unavailable](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#max-unavailable) (aka [Proportional Scaling](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#max-unavailable)), then at some point [pause your deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#max-unavailable) resume if everything looks good and then rollback if something went wrong.

The recommended way is really to use another deployment as [canary](https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-canary-deployments-for-mere-mortals-13728ce032fe) split the traffic through a load balancer between canary and non-canary, then if everything goes well upgrade the non-canary and shut down the canary. If something goes wrong shutdown the canary and keep the non-canary until the issue is fixed.

Another strategy is to use something like [Istio](https://istio.io/) that facilitates [canary deployments](https://istio.io/blog/2017/0.1-canary/).